# Failing on fetching packages when creating react app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am trying to create react app using: `npx create-react-app my-app`
and I keep getting this error:

```
Creating a new React app in /Users/mcohen/Git/andys-tale/andys-blog.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

yarn add v1.12.3
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
error https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@xtuc/ieee754/-/ieee754-1.2.0.tgz: Extracting tar content of undefined failed, the file appears to be corrupt: "Unexpected end of data"
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts --cwd /Users/mcohen/Git/andys-tale/andys-blog has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Deleting andys-blog/ from /Users/mcohen/Git/andys-tale
Done.
```

Any suggestions what shall I do?

Comment: I had the same problem but only on Gitlab CI builds. Clearing the runner caches fixed this error for me.

Comment: @frido, can you expand on what you mean by this? Running `yarn cache clean` in CI before the install command did not resolve this issue for me

Comment: @user7622212 I used gitlab.com. Under `YourProject > CI/CD > Pipelines` there is a button called `Clear runner caches`.

Answer (score 2):

Delete yarn.lock file
This will help!

Answer (score -1):

I'd probably desperately run yarn cache clean